# Are questions in Triage shown on the real-time tab?

Tags: support, stackexchange.com, triage, realtime-questions

Questions selected for Triage are not shown on site's front page. Do they appear on the network-wide [real-time question list](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=realtime)?

(Reason for asking: spam-detecting bots rely on the realtime question feed.)

Comment: Asking for [hichris123](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3017810#3017810).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They do right now. They may not always in the future.